# Watch QuickTime videos in the browser?

Tags: browser, plugins, quicktime

It's rather frustrating to me that I can't watch any of the videos on Apple's site. Is there a QuickTime plugin for Chrome or Firefox, and if not, why?

Answer (score 10):

Odd... Works for me!

I'm using the totem plugin which I thought shipped with Ubuntu. Have a look at `about:plugins` in the browser and see if you can see "QuickTime Plug-in 7.something"

If you don't, check `totem-mozilla` is installed. Might be worth installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package to make sure you've got the right codecs.

Just searching synaptic, I also have `libquicktime1` installed. It's a dependency of `quicktime-utils` so it might be worth installing that. It might just be something used for encoding to quicktime.

Edit: you might also need `gstreamer-plugins-bad` for AAC audio.

Comment: Installing `totem-mozilla` did it for me; I already had `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed.  Plugin works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

The Quicktime codec, like most other non-free formats, is provided as part of the `w32codecs` package (or its 64-bit equivalent, `w64codecs`) by [Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/). The community documentation includes [instructions for installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Playing%20Non-Native%20Media%20Formats).

Once the codecs are installed the standard media plugins for your browser should detect and handle them.

Comment: Got `w64codecs` installed on my Ubuntu 11.04, and at least Firefox's about:plugins shows "QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.6" (libtotem-narrowspace-plugin.so). Still, the QuickTime videos on Apple's site won't play...

Comment: @Jonik Medibuntu is by now severely deprecated.  Do not use it.  Try [Oli's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/1698/43660).

Comment: the instructions for installing link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered that sometimes Apple actually detects which browser/OS you're using when it embeds videos on its site, and that can prevent QuickTime videos from playing even if you have the proper codecs and plugins installed. You can circumvent this in Firefox by changing your user agent string.

You'll need the User Agent Switcher extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

And a user agent string that specifies a browser on Mac or Windows. There's a rather nice list of user agents here:
http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html

Comment: I tried to see some [videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) of WWDC by changing the user agent of Firefox to Safari on ubuntu 14.04. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to run the following from a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mplayer gecko-mediaplayer
```