# Which Firefox plugin should I choose for quicktime format?

Tags: firefox, plugins, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Watch QuickTime videos in the browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1695/watch-quicktime-videos-in-the-browser)

Firefox asked me to install missing plugin. And presented with four choices

[image]

What are the differences between these options? 
Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Please check this post [Play Quicktime](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1695/watch-quicktime-videos-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gecko Media Player (mplayer) is the best one.

referred by the following mozilla [link](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/quicktime-plugin-play-audio-and-video)